# Trouble with doors

Tags: metroid-prime-3-corruption

I'm working my way through Metroid Prime 3 again, and am being plagued with annoying bug that drove me crazy the first time: Doors don't always open.  I can be standing right in front of it, shoot the blue "shield", which disappears, but often the door itself doesn't open.  I can blast away at it or just stand and wait, but it delays for anywhere from one to thirty seconds before it finally decides to open.

It may just be my impression, but I feel like this happens more in some areas than in others.  Usually it's just an annoyance, though when I'm at 40 health and running away from a half-dozen Phaazoids, this is kind of a big deal.

Has anybody else had this problem? Is there any trick to encouraging doors to open faster?  Is this a bug, or is the game just loading the next room or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct with the idea that the game's loading the next room in the downtime between shooting the door and the door actually opening. The only thing you can do to help prevent yourself from being ambushed while stuck waiting for the game to load is to shoot the door as soon as you see it, letting the game load the next room while you make your way to the door.